# Is there a way to find the YouTube video from a Facebook video?

Tags: facebook, youtube, video

I often see videos on Facebook and would like to have a more permanent link to them. I would like to find the same video on YouTube. Is there a straightforward way to find the YouTube version of a Facebook video?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there is no direct way to do this.  My best suggestion is to combine unique/specific combination of words in either a Google or Youtube search for whatever video you see.  (eg - Snake bites water balloon)  If there's a specific video you're looking for I might be able to help...

Answer (score 2):

Facebook and YouTube are two different services. While I expect a lot of people (corporations, etc.) would upload to both in order to maximize the potential audience, there's no guarantee that they would.

Assuming they have posted on both, there's no "link" between the two. One will have been uploaded in one place, the other at the other. Each service will give it it's own filename (if it even exposes the filename). At best, you can do a general web search for the title of the video or, if the description on both is the same you can search on that.

So, no, there is no straightforward way to find the YouTube version of a Facebook video, assuming one exists.

Answer (score 1):

Take a screenshot of the video and google the screenshot

Comment: Could you give an example where Google Image search is good enough to do this?

Comment: @Christian If the image taken from the video is popular enough that people have taken screenshots to use for articles and stuff then it's safe to say that google searching the image would lead you to a YouTube video via its title.